# How to fix AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, gradle, build

I have seen this issue on several platforms, anyone knows what is it and how to fix it?

The error message:

```
AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.

Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.
```

build gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app name"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
```

pubspec:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_markdown: ^0.2.0
  share: ^0.5.3
  intl: ">=0.14.0"
  shared_preferences: ^0.4.3
  rxdart: ^0.19.0
  url_launcher: ^4.0.1
```

Comment: can you please put your pubspec.yaml file code?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has the same issue, it was a problem in package compatibility, in this case, was the obsolete shared preferences.